# Using jQuery's Bottom up Selector Approach

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am curious based on jQuery's Bottom up or Right to Left  query selecting.  How could this selector below be improved?

Not the actual `keydown` event but the `.undo` and `.save` portion of the code?

```
<div id="dnsTitle" class="account accountTitle">
    <div class="content">
         <h4>DNS records for:  <a href="http://testing3.com" target="_blank">testing3.com</a></h4>
    <div>

    <div class="actions">
        <a class="undo disabled">Undo Changes</a>
        <a class="save disabled">Save Changes</a>
        <a class="back" href="./?module=dns_manager">Domain List</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Selector

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#dnsRecords input" ,function() {
    $("#dnsTitle a.save, #dnsTitle a.undo").removeClass("disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var dnsTitle  = $("#dnsTitle");
$(document).on("keydown", "#dnsRecords input" ,function() {
    $(".save, .undo", dnsTitle  ).removeClass("disabled");
});
```

or

```
dnsTitle.find(".save, .undo").removeClass("disabled");
```

Checkout [this test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-performance-with-context) I created for your case, `dnsTitle.find(".save, .undo")` seems to be the fastest

For a selector comparison refer [this test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-context-comparison)

Comment: Nice thanks for the comparison link too, thats the kind of info I needed

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#dnsRecords input" ,function() {
    $("#dnsTitle").find(".save, .undo").removeClass("disabled");
});
```

Comment: Would you say using find() is generally faster?

Comment: @jasondavis yes look at the test I posted below

Comment: Yes, the old method of specifying the `selector` and `context` boils down to the pattern used above, so it's faster using `find()`.